# How to send a command with arguments without spaces?

Tags: bash, shell, command-line, terminal

Is there a way to execute a command with arguments in linux without whitespaces?

```
cat file.txt
```

needs to be:

```
cat(somereplacementforthiswhitespace)file.txt
```

Comment: if the file name is " file.txt" then can you can use cat \ file.txt (try \ followed by tab completion)

Comment: This is an example, i want to use more commands then only cat :( btw, I can't use any sort of whitespace, (tab is a whitespace)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

If only there was a variable whose value is a space… Or more generally, contains a space.

```
cat${IFS}file.txt
```

The default value of `IFS` is space, tab, newline. All of these characters are whitespace. If you need a single space, you can use `${IFS%??}`.

More precisely, the reason this works has to do with how word splitting works. Critically, it's applied after substituting the value of variables. And word splitting treats each character in the value of `IFS` as a separator, so by construction, as long as `IFS` is set to a non-empty value, `${IFS}` separates words. If `IFS` is more than one character long, each character is a word separator. Consecutive separator characters that are whitespace are treated as a single separator, so the result of the expansion of `cat${IFS}file.txt` is two words: `cat` and `file.txt`. Non-whitespace separators are treated separately, with something like `IFS=',.'; cat${IFS}file.txt`, `cat` would receive two arguments: an empty argument and `file.txt`.

Comment: This is great! How does this work? Why does ${IFS%?} evaluate to a space?

Comment: Awesome, that makes sense. I found documentation on the IFS var, but didn't understand the rest. Thank you for explaining!

Comment: @loneboat Actually, while my comment was correct, it was a bit misleading. I've edited my answer with a more detailed explanation.

Comment: Saved the day after a long search

Comment: `/bin/bash: sleep${IFS}0: command not found`

Comment: @PeterKionga-Kamau The context of the question was something like `bash -c 'sleep${IFS}0'`. Not something like `var='sleep${IFS}0'; bash -c "$var"`

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' noted & thanks, but would love to know how to do it from `$var` which is the only option in my case... hoping it's possible with the correct escaping of characters perhaps...

Comment: @PeterKionga-Kamau I don't know what you're trying to do here. Please post a new question with all the information.

Answer (score 9):

I found a way assuming a shell that supports `csh`-like brace expansion like `ksh`, `bash` or `yash -o brace-expand` (`zsh` supports brace expansion, but not as the first argument like that as that conflicts with command grouping):

```
{cat,file.txt}
```

with this way you don't have to use whitespaces in your argument.

Answer (score 3):

One alternative is to use the value of IFS with the expansion of a variable:

```
$ echo Hello! > file.txt

$ IFS=:
$ a=cat:file.txt
$ $a
Hello!
```

Answer (score -2):

OP was 6 years ago,

> time goes fast.

But I'm posting this for anyone that any of the previous answers didn't work for him,

like me personally for `cat${IFS%???}file.txt` or `{cat,*}`:
`command not found: cat file.txt` and `no matches found: ,cat,*`

Anyhow, i found a much simpler approach that worked for me which is:

```
cat<index.js
```

or for example:

```
cat<*
```

please don't use it in any unethical way thank you!

Comment: would this downvoter mind to explain his downvote?

Comment: I suppose you're using `zsh` (the only shell where `cat<*` actually works, and where `cat${IFS%???}file.txt` would return that error). Note that that  method can't be extended to  commands that take arguments. You could do `echo${=IFS}test${=IFS}*` though where `${=IFS}` is used so `$IFS` be subject to split+glob like it is in other Bourne-like shells.

Comment: `cat<*` works in bash too, but ya, you're correct, I am using zsh, thanks for the information!

Comment: What does your ending comment mean: please don't use it in any unethical way thank you!

Comment: `cat<*` only works in bash if `*` happens to expand to one and only one file (and bash is running interactively or with the posix option disabled).